# Can you have more than two componentInstances in a flexipage?

Tags: salesforce1-app, flexipages

I've been playing around with the new Flexipage functionality, and I can't seem to get more than two componentInstances to display on the page.  Two filterListCards works:

```
<componentInstances>
    <componentInstanceProperties>
        <name>entityName</name>
        <value>Delivery__c</value>
    </componentInstanceProperties>
    <componentInstanceProperties>
        <name>filterName</name>
        <value>Todays_Deliveries</value>
    </componentInstanceProperties>
    <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
</componentInstances>
<componentInstances>
    <componentInstanceProperties>
        <name>entityName</name>
        <value>Delivery__c</value>
    </componentInstanceProperties>
    <componentInstanceProperties>
        <name>filterName</name>
        <value>Future_Deliveries</value>
    </componentInstanceProperties>
    <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
</componentInstances>
```

one filterListCard and one recentItems works:

```
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>entityName</name>
            <value>Delivery__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>filterName</name>
            <value>Future_Deliveries</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>entityNames</name>
            <value>Delivery__c,Return_Item__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:recentItems</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
```

However, 2 filterListCards and 1 recentItems does not work:

```
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>entityName</name>
            <value>Delivery__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>filterName</name>
            <value>Todays_Deliveries</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>entityName</name>
            <value>Delivery__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>filterName</name>
            <value>Future_Deliveries</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>entityNames</name>
            <value>Delivery__c,Return_Item__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:recentItems</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
```

Is this a limitation of the flexipage, or am I missing something here.  I couldn't seem to find any documentation on limits of how many componentInstances there could be in a flexipage

Comment: is the page giving any error? What behaviour are you experiencing?

Comment: hm - this is weird - I re-uploaded the flexipage so I can show the error message and now it's working...  It's either I did something wrong the first time, or salesforce may have fixed something :shrug:

Answer (score 3):

There **is** a limitation on the number of components that you can have in a flexipage, however it's 25 and not 2.

This is stated in the Salesforce1 developer guide on page 155:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf

I don't see anything wrong with your flexipage though...

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the different listviews separately


    
        
            
                entityName
                Session__c
            
            
                filterName
                All_NSTM_Attendee_Sessions
            
            flexipage:filterListCard

```
    <componentInstances>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>entityName</name>
            <value>Session__c</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentInstanceProperties>
            <name>filterName</name>
            <value>Pyxis_Sessions</value>
        </componentInstanceProperties>
        <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
    </componentInstances>


    <name>main</name>
</flexiPageRegions>

<masterLabel>Sessions</masterLabel>
```